# Swing: binding complex object list with jtable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, binding

I'm developping a small application in Swing with Netbeans. I currently can display a list of objects in a jTable with Binding. But one of the object's properties is another object:

```
public class CustomProp {
    private String description;
    private int value;

    //constructor, getters and setters...
}

public class MainObject {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private boolean aBoolProp;
    private CustomProp myCustomProp;

    //constructors, getters and setters...
}
```

I have a arraylist with 4 instanced MainObjects named mainObjectsList. The jTable Elements binding espression is `${mainObjectsList}`

Then in the jTable, I can see my objects properties but in myCustomProps column, I can see only the object address (mytest.CustomProp@64ca87d5). Is it possible to configure the Binding expression to display the parameters of the object property in the jTable?

Comment: You would probably need to set the TableModel's column class correctly and provide a custom render for your `CustomProp`. Alternatively you can change the `toString` method of `CustomProp` to return what you want - that's a little hacky however.

Comment: @BoristheSpider your comment should be an answer

Comment: which "binding" exactly are you talking about? if it's the old beansbinding, you can use a path expression, like _customProp.name_ for the TableColumnBinding. Other binding frameworks have most probably support something similar

Comment: @StanislavL added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand what is going on you need to understand how a `JTable` turns what you give it into a displayable component.

This is does using a [`TableCellRenderer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html). What this essentially does it create a `JLabel` for each table cell that contains a `String` representation of the data.

The default renderer doesn't have any idea about your `CustomProp` type so all it does it call `toString` on it to get a `String` representation and display it.

This opens one avenue - change the `toString` of your `CustomProp`. This approach will work, but is hacky for a number of reasons:

1. Your object should not really be tempting itself, this is a violation of separation of concerns.
2. You `toString` method may well be used elsewhere, in logging for example, and the representation that makes sense in the table will not make sense there
3. `toString` should not really be part of an object's contract - it should be changeable when new fields are added etc. If you use the representation in the table then that is not the case (see 1.)

Having said that, [Joshua Bloch's](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html) Item 10 ("Always override toString") does state that `toString` can be part of an object's contract if it is heavily documented.

Personally, I would prefer to set the column class of the `TableModel` by extending [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html):

```
private static final class MyTableModel extends DefaultTableModel {

    private static final int CUSTOM_PROP_COL = 1;

    //various required constructors, call super(...)

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(final int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == CUSTOM_PROP_COL) {
            return CustomProp.class;
        }
        return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
    }

}
```

Then you need to set this model rather than the default when you build your `JTable`:

```
final MyTableModel myTableModel = /*create as usual*/  
final JTable jTable = new JTable(myTableModel);
```

Now your table knows the class of the column with `CustomProp`. Create a custom renderer to render the column:

```
private static final class CustomPropRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        final CustomProp prop = (CustomProp) value;
        final StringBuilder representation = new StringBuilder();
        //build a string representation of prop
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, representation.toString(), isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }

}
```

And tell your `JTable` to use your renderer for columns of class `CustomProp`:

```
jTable.setDefaultRenderer(CustomProp.class, new CustomPropRenderer());
```

**EDIT**

Following @kleopatra's comment and noticing the [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) tag I did a quick google and found [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1162166/beansbinding-a-jtable-in-netbeans). Looks like it is either exactly what is required (or possible completely irrelevant).

You should be able to use `${customProp.property}` as the binding for the column.

Comment: while correct, most probably not needed: the OP is using a binding framework - simply bind the property via a path expression

Comment: @kleopatra the OP seems to be binding an object to a table row - so might need to provide a renderer for individual columns - at least that was my impression.

Comment: repeating: most probably not, the framework will do it - somthing like `new TableColumnBinding(BeansProperty.create("customProperty.name"))`

Comment: Giving answer tag to Boris but your comment was really helpful too Kleopatra. Thank you very much everyone, I will try the column binding, and eventually use tablemodel later if it is really better.